# How light source effects the nature of electron in double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I know that electrons behaves as a particle instead of waves once observed under a light source. 
But what I really want to know is that how the photon particles are forcing the electrons to deviate from their wave character?

Comment: Well, your first sentence is not correct, so you are right to question how it could possibly be. It can't, so no worries...

Comment: Then why we aren’t getting the interference pattern once we use a light source to detect the electrons?

Comment: How are you using a light source to detect the electrons? What do you mean by that?

Comment: While performing the double slit experiment we can see when both the slits are opened we get an interference pattern so to locate the position of electrons we use detectors and a dim light source to check from which slit the electrons are passing. So whenever we get the sound we could see that an electron is passed through either of the slits but then the pattern disappears only when the photons are unable to detect them we are getting the pattern. So why is it that while measuring the position of electrons they are behaving like particles?

Comment: Okay I got the answer

Comment: see this https://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html#jCp and the explanation therein